# Is it really unhealthy to eat meat and drink milk mainly?

Tags: diet

Some Westerners used to eat meat and drink milk mainly. But experts warn us about the importance of vegetables in our diet. I've learned on the Internet that milk and meat are staples in Mongolian cuisine. Tea may be the substitute for vegetables. However, the life expectancy of the Mongolians is not as short as we guess. So I'm curious about if the advice from experts is sound.

Comment: Hello ;  welcome ; I have suggested an edit trying to improve the question by means of clarifying the **question** in the session and make it more communal. You are welcome to review and accept or reject.

Comment: Well, sadly you have rejected the edit which is available here: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/19752

Comment: I hope other community members will review it and opinion that it actually improved the question somewhat.

Comment: There are a couple of detailed answers about milk [here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/16584/is-cow-milk-unhealthy/16589#16589) and about red meat on [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19625/does-red-meat-increase-the-risk-of-heart-disease/23636#23636).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because nutrition is off-topic on Medical Sciences unless the question is related to a medical treatment.

Comment: @BryanKrause Nutrition is off-topic? How did this question get through? https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/88/15865

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar "Asked 7 years, 2 months ago" Policies change, and it's not worth our time to go back and purge old questions that don't follow newer rules, or fair to people who spent time answering a question that was allowed when it was asked just because something changed later.

Comment: @BryanKrause I see, that makes sense, thanks. I hadn't noticed the age of that post.